# Java Thread error

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, chat

here is the problem, the code below worked fine in console, but now when I implemented it to Jframe it gives error. Here is my code

```
 private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
  try{
     DataInputStream Din= new DataInputStream(server_socket.getInputStream());
     String input_string= Din.readUTF();
     ChatArea.append(input_string);
      while(true){
                  ReadMessageThread rmt= new ReadMessageThread(server_socket);
                  new Thread(rmt).start();
      }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}  


}                                 

class ReadMessageThread implements Runnable {
    Socket threadSocket;
    String incoming_message;
    public  ReadMessageThread(Socket socket){
        threadSocket=socket;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try {
               DataInputStream input= new DataInputStream(threadSocket.getInputStream());

            while (true) {
                String incoming_message = input.readUTF();
                ChatArea.append(incoming_message);
            }
        } catch(IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I can send message to server it's fine, but I can't get message sent by server. 
P.S. It's a chatroom and this is a client side of code. 
Thank you

Comment: Please fix formatting!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: You're creating an infinite number of Threads in you while(true) loop! Is this intended?

Comment: @isnot2bad Yes, it needs to read for incoming message from server all the time

Comment: @MBP I'm not talking about reading messages! You're continously creating Threads in an infinite loop.

Comment: @isnot2bad oh thanks man, how i could miss it, :))) i have been looking for solution for 2 days now. stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't do `while(true)` in handlers of Swing events: these are executed on the Swing's thread, that was doing things like

- open the window
- call the event handler just in case
- draw the window
- call that event handler
- now put components into the window

and so on. If you block forever in your handler, the application will appear stuck.

What you should do is something like

```
handleEvent() {
  new ListenerThread().start();
}

// ...
ListenerThread {
  @Override public void run() {
    while(true) { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```